# What is the purpose of AngularJS it() and describe() functions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some projects in Javascript/JQuery but AngularJS is a whole new concept to me.

In the docs I have seen the following functions appear alot of time.

```
describe('PhoneListCtrl', function(){

  it('should create "phones" model with 3 phones', function() {
    var scope = {},
        ctrl = new PhoneListCtrl(scope);

    expect(scope.phones.length).toBe(3);
  });

});
```

Are `describe()` and `it()` legitimate functions? From the tutorial docs I understand that they are for testing and mock up, but it is still unclear to me how I should run these functions, and if they are merely used as 'foo' and 'bar'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`describe` is used to scope tests and `it` is used to declare them. When the test fails, in your case, you would see a message along the lines of

```
'should create "phones" model with 3 phones' FAILED!
```

Followed by some failing assertions. The string provided to `it` gives context to the assertions.

`describe` can be used to scope a number of tests to a single topic. Including `before` and `after` functions. This is common in lots of testing libraries, not just in javascript. Mocha, Jasmine, but also rspec (from Ruby) use a similar approach.

Comment: I find the string following it() to be really weird in a coding context, but now I get its use, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

These are from the [Jasmine testing framework](https://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html). `describe` defines a test suite, and `it` defines a "spec" or a test. From the Jasmine documentation:

> A test suite begins with a call to the global Jasmine function
>   `describe` with two parameters: a string and a function. The string is a
>   name or title for a spec suite - usually what is under test. The
>   function is a block of code that implements the suite.

and regarding `it`:

> Specs are defined by calling the global Jasmine function `it`, which,
>   like describe takes a string and a function. The string is a title for
>   this spec and the function is the spec, or test. A spec contains one
>   or more expectations that test the state of the code under test.

I am not familiar with Angular, but my assumption is that this is perhaps used in the documentation for illustrative purposes in a style similar to that used by the various code koans such as [Ruby Koans](http://rubykoans.com/), where tests are used to illustrate how certain aspects of the language are meant to function. I could be wrong about that last part though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, +1! If only I can accept all answers I would do so!

Comment: @iWillGetBetter no problem. The accepted answer is a better answer to your question. I actually don't know much about the topic, and was just exercising my google-foo. Thanks for the upvote anyway ;)